# ASP.NET GridView using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selection

I have a problem with gridview, I am using a gridview and listview on a page, when I select a row in the gridview I want to insert the data into the listview based on selection in the gridview. I am using a primary key in gridview.

PLease help me out

Comment: [Straight from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972814.aspx), showing how to drill-down for information based on gridview selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also called "Master-Detail".

You can find a great [tutorial here](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs).

In short, you need to make the row selectable.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductsGrid" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
    DataSourceID="AllProductsDataSource" EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName"
         HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice"
          DataFormatString="{0:c}" HeaderText="Unit Price"
          HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is done with `<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />` in the code above.

The next step is to add you `DetailsView` to be binded to the selected element of the master gridview. This can be done because the selection return the primary key of the element, from there you can load the detail.

This do a PostBack, if you want you can use Ajax and remove the PostBack flickering.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the select on the gridview should fire off the event SelectedIndexChanged(). You would use that event to create the datasource for your listview and then bind the datasource to your listview.

Comment: +1: It's a good answer, but in the future you should post a small example to demonstrate, especially since OP did not post any example code.